# How to move and resize Ubuntu's ext4 and linux-swap logical partitions?

Tags: gparted, unallocated

EDIT:

Ended up fiddling around and found this out:

I needed to delete the Swap partition, add the unallocated space to the extended partition, then add the unallocated space to my ext4 partition before creating a new Swap partition.

I don't remember resizing my Ubuntu partition as being this overly complicated, though.

Comment: My guess is that what you've described as the unallocated space being in the Linux partition is that the unallocated space is inside the extended partition container (that has both of Ubuntu's partitions inside it). What happens when you try to move the swap partition to the right? If it's grayed out or the interface otherwise is not allowing it (but without giving any errors or other messages), can you add another screenshot to show the situation now? Also, what do you mean by "*swap is off on my Linux partition*"? Do you mean the live system, on which GParted is running, is not swapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it while your partitions are mounted, so as alluded to: download the [GParted ISO](http://gparted.org/) burn it to a disc and then boot off of that.  It will allow you to resize your partitions to your heart's content.  Be warned: as with any low-level disk operations there is always the possibility of data loss so if there is anything important you have that you don't have a backup of then create one first.